# How do I get a list of all the GitHub projects I've contributed to in the last year?

Tags: api, events, github

I realize I can hit `https://api.github.com/users/:user_id/repos` to get a list of all the repos I own or have forked. But what I would like to do is figure out all of the projects I have contributed to (commits, pull requests, issues, etc.) over the last year. The [events API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events-performed-by-a-user) lets me get the last 300 events, but I have contributed a *lot* more than that in the last twelve months. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [a tweet](https://twitter.com/Caged/status/426914436226351104) from [@caged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26876/caged), I wrote [this Perl script](https://gist.github.com/theory/8677613) to iterate over months in [my contributions](https://github.com/theory?tab=contributions):

```
use v5.12;
use warnings;
use utf8;
my $uname = 'theory';

my %projects;
for my $year (2012..2014) {
    for my $month (1..12) {
        last if $year == 2014 && $month > 1;
        my $from = sprintf '%4d-%02d-01', $year, $month;
        my $to   = sprintf '%4d-%02d-01', $month == 12 ? ($year + 1, 1) : ($year, $month + 1);
        my $res = `curl 'https://github.com/$uname?tab=contributions&from=$from&to=$to' | grep 'class="title"'`;
        while ($res =~ /href="([^"?]+)/g) {
            my (undef, $user, $repo) = split m{/} => $1;
            $projects{"$user/$repo"}++;
        }
    }
}

say "$projects{$_}: $_" for sort keys %projects;
```

Yeah, HTML scraping is kind of ugly, but did the trick for my needs.

Comment: This works for public contributions only.  Any way to get private contributions using curl?  I've tried basic auth, but don't seem to be having any luck...

Comment: I needed this again, but sadly it doesn't work anymore, since various bits get loaded via JS now. :-(