# GithubAPI: Get repositories a user has ever committed in

Tags: git, github, github-api

Within the scope of the research project ideally I need for any two users find the   repositories that they have in their shared history of public development, i.e. they have committed in the same repos.

I wonder if it is possible to get the list of repositories that were ever been touched by a given user.

In Github-API I can see only:

1. `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/contributors`
2. `GET /users/:user/repos`
3. `GET /users/:user/events`

First gives only the contributors for a given `:repo` repository
Second only gives a `:user`'s repos
Third was promising, but events are limited to 300

Is there any way to get all the repositories a user has ever worked with on Github without dumping all 3 millions repos?

Comment: Not possible currently. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322778/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-github-projects-ive-contributed-to-in-the-last-y and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714593/github-api-repositories-contributed-to

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the github search api: https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-code

one catch is that you have to specify a query, so for example if I lookup my name with the query 'def' you would get: https://api.github.com/search/code?q=def+user:manuelvanrijn