# Github API v3 Events to retrieve all events through api

Tags: api, events, github, limit, commit

I wanted to confirm that the GitHub API for [events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) provides only the latest 300 events only or is can I get the entire list of events?

Comment: Also, can someone please tell me how to retrieve list of CreateEvents in a repo ?

Comment: Also, after analyzing that I can get only commits only a year back. Is there any way to get all the commits from the start of a repository

Comment: The documentation states it is limited to last 300 events and last 90 days, which I confirm is the case. It would be very helpful to me if there was a way to circumvent this limitation. Notice that on a GitHub user profile, at the "Contribution activity" section, you can explore up to the beginning. So maybe there is some hacky way to find back all events.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of searching led me to this answer on another question: [How do I get a list of all the GitHub projects I've contributed to in the last year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322778/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-github-projects-ive-contributed-to-in-the-last-y#32465169)

The application is hosted at [opensourcecontributo.rs](https://opensourcecontributo.rs/). Simply input your GitHub username, then you will have two tabs to use, allowing you to list *all* the repositories you contributed to, and *all* your events. The source code is available on GitHub at [tenex/opensourcecontributors](https://github.com/tenex/opensourcecontributors).

I guess this application does what I suggested in my comment to your question: for recent data it may just use the API, and for older data it may use the timeline to enumerate repositories, then use the API to inspect these repositories. I definitely have to take a look at this code.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that GitHub's API doesn't limit you to 300 events, but instead only events that have occurred in the last 90 days

> Only events created within the past 90 days will be included in timelines. > > Events older than 90 days will not be included (even if the total number of > events in the timeline is less than 300).
>
> https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-public-events-for-a-user

If you are looking for the raw number of events that a user created on any day historically through their account, I created a [script](https://github.com/proselotis/miscellaneous_scripts/blob/main/get_contributions_count.py) that works within GitHub's current HTML display and web scraping instead of using their API (as I can't find a way to acquire this kind of data through their API). As a note, the details of each event although can be displayed in the UI, is activated by private calls so I don't believe there is an easy way to access that data.